# Odd number $N$ which does not divide $2^k-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there does not exist a composite odd number $N > 1$ which does not divide $2^k-1$ for $k = 1,2,\ldots,N-2$.

I conjectured this result, but wasn't sure how to prove it. I tried it for many cases and it seems to be true.

Answer (score 4):

There are less than $N-1$ integers $a,0<a<N,$ such that $\gcd(a,N)=1$. This is because $N$ is composite, so some $a$:s in that range are excluded. At least the factors of $N$, and their multiples that are $<N$.

Because powers of two are coprime to $N$, they fall into one of the residue classes of those integers $a$. By the pigeon-hole principle there are two exponents $0\le i<j< N-1$ such that
$2^i\equiv2^j\pmod{N}$. But then
$$
N\mid 2^{j-i}-1.
$$

---

Of course, we can also say more precisely that $N\mid 2^{\phi(N)}-1$, where
$\phi(N)$ is the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) function. This can sharpened by using the Carmichael function instead. If we know the full prime factorization of $N$, then computing either the Euler or Carmichael function is straight forward. Without that we can still say that an exponent $<N-1$ will work.

Comment: As usual, it is possible that this is a duplicate. My search-fu failed, but ping me, if you find one.